# What does “Plan Rows: 0” mean in PostgreSQL query plan?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

This query shows "Plan Rows: 0" in the query plan.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
   EMP_ID CHAR(4),
   EMP_NAME VARCHAR(200)
);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ( '1000', 'JOHN DOE' );
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ( '1001', 'ALAN SMITHEE' );
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ( '1002', 'JANE DOE' );
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, FORMAT JSON)
   SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMP_ID = NULL;
```

Result:

```
[ { "Plan": {
   "Node Type": "Result",
   "Parallel Aware": false,
   "Startup Cost": 0.00,
   "Total Cost": 0.00,
   "Plan Rows": 0,
   "Plan Width": 438,
   "Actual Startup Time": 0.001,
   "Actual Total Time": 0.001,
   "Actual Rows": 0,
   "Actual Loops": 1,
   "One-Time Filter": "false"
},
"Planning Time": 0.023,
"Triggers": [ ],
"Execution Time": 0.011 } ]
```

What does "Plan Rows: 0" in this query plan mean?

1. PostgreSQL didn't scan any record,  because `EMP_ID = NULL` is always false.
2. PostgreSQL scanned the `EMP` table, because stats may different from the actual table content.

Comment: Unrelated but: most people prefer the text output using `explain (analyze,  format text)` (or simply `explain (analyze)`) - the JSON format is more intended for an automatic analysis through e.g. a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL detects that `emp_id = NULL` is always false, so it doesn't scan the table at all, but returns an empty result right away.

“Plan Rows” is the estimated number of result rows and is 0 because PostgreSQL *knows* that there can be no result row. Normally, when PostgreSQL cannot be certain, it will estimate at least one result to avoid very bad plans in case its estimate is off.

Answer (score -2):

The analyze will scan the table every time and because your condition is always false it will always return 0 planned rows. If you keep inserting rows without truncating the table you will see the cost begin to rise as your rowcount increases, due to the extra time spent checking the where condition.

From the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/using-explain.html:

> The rows value is a little tricky because it is not the number of rows processed or scanned by the plan node, but rather the number emitted by the node. This is often less than the number scanned, as a result of filtering by any WHERE-clause conditions that are being applied at the node. Ideally the top-level rows estimate will approximate the number of rows actually returned, updated, or deleted by the query.

from an example shown in the linked documentation:

> Notice that the EXPLAIN output shows the WHERE clause being applied as a "filter" condition attached to the Seq Scan plan node. **This means that the plan node checks the condition for each row it scans, and outputs only the ones that pass the condition. The estimate of output rows has been reduced because of the WHERE clause. However, the scan will still have to visit all 10000 rows**, so the cost hasn't decreased; in fact it has gone up a bit (by 10000 * cpu_operator_cost, to be exact) to reflect the extra CPU time spent checking the WHERE condition.

Comment: This answer has little connection to the question.